# Remove Double quote from json Data

Tags: c#, json

Hello friends I have Some issue with jquery json. Below is my Json:

```
var dataSet2=[{"label":"Label 1","data":"[[1,10],[2,20],[3,10],[4,25],[5,15],[6,20],[7,40]]","color":"#3498db"},{"label":"Label 2","data":"[[1,15],[2,30],[3,25],[4,55],[5,30],[6,45],[7,50]]","color":"#e74c3c"}]
```

I want my Json Like:

```
 var dataSet2=[{"label":"Label 1","data":[[1,10],[2,20],[3,10],[4,25],[5,15],[6,20],[7,40]],"color":"#3498db"},{"label":"Label 2","data":[[1,15],[2,30],[3,25],[4,55],[5,30],[6,45],[7,50]],"color":"#e74c3c"}]
```

need to remove double quotes

```
"[[1,10],[2,20],[3,10],[4,25],[5,15],[6,20],[7,40]]"

"[[1,15],[2,30],[3,25],[4,55],[5,30],[6,45],[7,50]]"
```

I have done with replace string option but its not working with my var dataSet2.

. Your help will be appreciable. Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no difference between json string one and two....

Comment: @Paebbels you can see the quotes with '[[' ,']]'.

Comment: Now I found it. Maybe you should describe for others where the difference is. It's not our task to use a diff tool to find a change of 4 characters out of 206.... The solution: Use a regular expression for string replacements that matches on `"data":"[[`, number pairs and `]]"`. If you are sure that pattern is very uniqure, you can try a fixed string replacement.

Comment: @Paebbels I have done with replace string option but its not working with my variable var dataSet2..:(

Comment: Please add your previous approaches to your questions, so we can try to correct or solve them.

Comment: @Paebbels No, that's not the solution. This is an XY Problem.

Comment: Anyone Let me know why giving -1 ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is not "remove double quotes". You need to either (a) parse the JSON arrays that are in the form of strings, or (b) produce the correct JSON in the first place.

You haven't shown us any of your C# code so I can't help you with (b), but for (a), you can do this:

```js
var dataSet2 = [
  {"label": "Label 1", "data": "[[1,10],[2,20],[3,10],[4,25],[5,15],[6,20],[7,40]]", "color": "#3498db"}, 
  {"label": "Label 2", "data": "[[1,15],[2,30],[3,25],[4,55],[5,30],[6,45],[7,50]]", "color": "#e74c3c"}
];

// parse and replace .data properties
dataSet2.forEach(function(item) {
  item.data = JSON.parse(item.data);
});


console.log(dataSet2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help its working...:)

Comment: but that's not C#, is it?

Comment: @stefankmitph No, it's Javascript, as is the code in the question. As I said, I can't help him with his C# if he hasn't shown it to us, but it's clear that he's consuming it in Javascript, so parsing it after the fact is one solution.

Comment: @JLRishe yeah, you're right. first he said (now it's edited already): it's not working in C#. of course this won't work in C#. very unclear question. but you've helped him anyways.

Comment: @stefankmitph Ah, I see. :) The comment had already been edited when I saw it.

Comment: @JLRishe look at the 6th comment below the question :)

Comment: `var dataset2 = ` is not a clear indicator for JS it is also valid in C#.

Comment: @Paebbels yes. but `var dataset2 = [{"data": "..."}]` is a very clear indicator for: this won't work in c#.

Answer (score 0):

your json string won't work anyway... (you have to have double quotes at the beginning and end)

try this:

```
string json = "[{\"label\":\"Label 1\",\"data\":[[1,10],[2,20],[3,10],[4,25],[5,15],[6,20],[7,40]],\"color\":\"#3498db\"},{\"label\":\"Label 2\",\"data\":[[1,15],[2,30],[3,25],[4,55],[5,30],[6,45],[7,50]],\"color\":\"#e74c3c\"}]";
```

Use [JSON formatter](http://www.freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html) to get an escaped (and usable) string out of it.

Comment: actually without quotes its working.